# Microsoft SQL server: copy table from linked server to current database using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am using Microsoft SQL server. the following code works if run from a QUERY:

```
SELECT * 
INTO mydatabase.dbo.atable 
FROM linkedserver.sandbox.dbo.atable
```

but it does not if inserted into a stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dataMigration   
AS  BEGIN   
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.     

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- Insert statements for procedure here     
SELECT *     
INTO mydatabase.dbo.atable  
FROM linkedserver.sandbox.dbo.atable   

 END   
GO
```

Command(s) completes successfully but no table is created into mydatabase. Sorry for the trivial question. I had a look at similar issues but i did not find a case similar to mine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this normal table or local temp table `#table1`?

Comment: atable might or not exist into mydatabase. Once copied from linkedserver.sandbox.dbo.atable will be used to populate other tables on mydatabase.

Comment: Try with: `SELECT * INTO mydatabase.dbo.atable FROM OPENQUERY([linkedserver],
    'SELECT * FROM sandbox.dbo.atable')`

Comment: One thing does your table contain VARBINARY/XML column in remote server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute the stored Procedure after you run the code to alter it.

try running:

```
exec dataMigration
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click[Option Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWImF.png) the store procedure and click "Execute Store procedure"